# How to number each occurrence of a substring in a cell in Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I'm fairly new to Power Query and have hit a hiccup that's been bothering me all day. I've read multiple threads here and on the Power BI community and none has really cleared my question, and my logic suggests a few different options to achieve what I want, but my lack of experience blocks any solution I attempt.

Context: 
I'm building a database for product import/export into WooCommerce, eBay and other channels; which takes some inputs by the (non tech savyy) users in Excel and develops several of the required fields. One of those is the image file names for each product.

I have this columns (in a much larger query table):

```
| ImageBaseName    | ImageQTY |                    ImageIDs                            |
| product-name.jpg |    3     |   product-name.jpg product-name.jpg product-name.jpg   |
| other-product.jpg|    5     |other-product.jpg other-product.jpg...other-product.jpg |
```

And my desired output would be:

```
| ImageBaseName    | ImageQTY |                         ImageIDs                             |
| product-name.jpg |    3     |   product-name-1.jpg product-name-2.jpg product-name-3.jpg   |
| other-product.jpg|    5     |other-product-1.jpg other-product-2.jpg...other-product-5.jpg |
```

In fact I don't need the two first columns if I get the ImageIDs like that.
The *ImageBaseName* column is generated from the input product name.
The *ImageQTY* column is direct input by the user.
The *ImageIDs* column I got so far is from using:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"previous step", "ImageIDs", each Text.Trim(Text.Repeat ([ImageBaseName]&" ", [ImageQty])))
```

And these are the options I've considered thus far:

**Option 1:** Text.Combine(Text.Split *ImageIDs* and **(somehow)** count and number each item in the list) and concatenate it all back... Which would probably start like this: Text.Combine(Text.Split,,,

**Option 2** Using the UI, splitting the *ImageIDs* by each space and by a high number of columns (as I don't know how many images each product will have, but probably no more than 12) and then assign a number suffix to each of those columns and then putting it all back together, but it feels messy as hell.

**Option 3** Probably theres a clean calculated way to generate the numbered image base names based on the number in the second column, and then attach the .jpg at the end of each, but honestly I don't know how.

I'd like it to be on the same table as I am already dealing with different queries...

Any help would be gladly accepted.

Comment: I think that your best bet would be to create a function where you call the function using the ImageBaseName, ImageQTY and the return string would be your result.

Comment: What do you mean... Like a "For" loop? Within Power Query? I'd rather to not include VBA in Excel directly because I can't trust the users to know how to enable macros when opening the file in their devices...

Comment: Users dont have to open VBA and run a macro for using UDFs(User Defined Functions). If someone insert a module in excel workbook and defines a function as in the answer and saves the workbook, the function will remain available forever in the workbook or its copies. even if they are shared/sent over email to other users. Users will just have to use it on excel sheet. Thus functions are different from macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a chunky "uber step" piece of code you could put in a custom column given the ImageBaseName and ImageQty columns

```
Text.Combine
(
    List.Transform
    (
        List.Zip
        (
            {
            List.Repeat({Text.BeforeDelimiter([ImageBaseName], ".", {0, RelativePosition.FromEnd})},[ImageQTY])
            ,
            List.Transform({1..[ImageQTY]}, each "-" & Number.ToText(_) &".")
            ,
            List.Repeat({Text.AfterDelimiter([ImageBaseName], ".", {0, RelativePosition.FromEnd})}, [ImageQTY])
            }
        )
    , each Text.Combine(_)
    )
, " "
)
```

Summary is you create the components of your string as 3 lists (text before file type, numbers 1 through qty, text after file type). Then you use List.Zip which combines the three text components into their own lists. Then we convert those lists back to a single piece of text with List.Transform and Text.Combine.

Comment: Hello @Wedge, 

Thanks for this, I will mark it as the solution, because it was the simplest I found and it didn't had any errors. I simplified it, by removing the **.jpg** from ImageBaseName (on the step that field was created) so based on your solution it looks like this:
`#"ImageIDsFromList" = Table.AddColumn (#"PreviousStep", "ImageIDsList", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.Zip({List.Repeat({[ImageBaseName]},[ImageQTY]),List.Transform({1..[ImageQTY]}, each "-" & Number.ToText(_) & ".jpg ")}), each Text.Combine(_)), " ")),` and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with this as Table1:

[image]

This M code...

```
let
    Source = Table1,
    SplitAndIndexImageIDs = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.FromColumns({Text.Split([ImageIDs]," ")}),"Index",1)),
    RenameImageIDs = Table.AddColumn(SplitAndIndexImageIDs, "NewImageIDs", each Text.Combine(Table.AddColumn([Custom],"newcolumn",each Text.BeforeDelimiter([Column1], ".") & "-" &Text.From([Index]) & "." & Text.AfterDelimiter([Column1], "."))[newcolumn],", ")),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(RenameImageIDs,{"ImageBaseName", "ImageQTY", "NewImageIDs"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns1"
```

Should give you this result:

[image]

Comment: Hello Marc, excuse the delay in my response, your solution seemed very elegant and short, I modified it a bit, to made it simpler:

So what I did is remove the .jpg from [ImageBaseName] and then:
`#"SplitAndIndexImageIDs" = Table.AddColumn(#"PreviousStep", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.FromColumns({Text.Split([ImageIDs]," ")}),"Index",1)),
    #"RenameImageIDs" = Table.AddColumn(SplitAndIndexImageIDs, "NewImageIDs", each Text.Combine(Table.AddColumn([Custom],"newcolumn",each [Column1] & "-" &Text.From([Index]) & ".jpg")[newcolumn],", ")),`

Comment: However, since some cells have null values, the "custom" column and the resulting "newImageIDs" display some errors, of course I can replace them with null again, but I don't like to replace errors... How would you validate with a conditional wrapping the whole thing or each step?

Comment: Which cells have the nulls?

Comment: If you're saying the nulls are in the ImageIDs cells, then maybe this will work for you: `#"SplitAndIndexImageIDs" = Table.AddColumn(#"PreviousStep", "Custom",  each if [ImageIDs] <> null then Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.FromColumns({Text.Split([ImageIDs]," ")}),"Index",1) else ""), 
    #"RenameImageIDs" = Table.AddColumn(SplitAndIndexImageIDs, "NewImageIDs", each try Text.Combine(Table.AddColumn([Custom],"newcolumn",each [Column1] & "-" &Text.From([Index]) & ".jpg")[newcolumn],", ") otherwise null)`

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume range Table1 contains two columns **ImageBaseName** and **Quantity**

Add column ... Index column...
Right Click **ImageBaseName** Split Column...By Delimiter...  --Custom--, use a period as the delimiter and split at Right-most delimiter.  That will pull the image suffix off

Add Column ... Custom Column ... name it **list**  and use formula **={1..[Quantity]}** which will create a list of values from 1 to the Quantity

Click the double arrow at the top of the new **list** column and choose expand to new rows

Click-Select the **list**, **Quantity**, **ImageBaseName.2**, **ImageBaseName.1** columns and Transform ... Data Type...Text

Add Column .. Custom Column .. name it **Custom** and use formula **=[ImageBaseName.1]&"-"&[list]&"."&[ImageBaseName.2]** to put together all the parts

Right-click  **Index** Group By ... [x] Basic, Group By **index**, new column name **ImageIDs**, Operation count rows

That will generate code like this:

```
Table.Group(#"Added Custom1", {"Index"}, {{"ImageIDs", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}})
```

Use formula bar to change the formula as shown below.  It will combine rows using , as a separator

```
Table.Group(#"Added Custom1", {"Index"}, {{"ImageIDs", each Text.Combine([Custom], ", "), type text}})
```

Full sample code is below that you can paste into Home .. Advanced Editor...

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Added Index", "ImageBaseName", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"."}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"ImageBaseName.1", "ImageBaseName.2"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "list", each {1..[Quantity]}),
#"Expanded list" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "list"),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded list",{{"list", type text}, {"Quantity", type text}, {"ImageBaseName.2", type text}, {"ImageBaseName.1", type text}}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Custom", each [ImageBaseName.1]&"-"&[list]&"."&[ImageBaseName.2]),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom1", {"Index"}, {{"ImageIDs", each Text.Combine([Custom], ", "), type text}})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

There are probably many ways to combine all this into one uber step, but I thought I'd show the parts

Comment: Thanks for the extensive reply, I didn't marked your answer as the solution, as it had many more steps than the others, but your detailed explaining allowed me to understand what was needed.